# Simplest way to return header of max value in a row (for a dynamic range)?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [sheet with a table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Azwb4Q6P4qX2SPjE2YelvajBfvBgZMQwL9OlEJQVKCo/edit#gid=0), where I want to extract the header of the max value in each row. The simple solution for that is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(B2<>"Sa",B2<>"Su"),INDEX($C$1:$Y$1,MATCH(MAX(C2:Y2),C2:Y2,0)),"weekend"),"")
```

Problem is, that if you insert a column to the right on column Y, the formula will not change the range (it will still be C2:Y2, and data on column Z will not be included). For that I created this formula, which solves this issue:

`=iferror(if(AND(B2<>"la";B2<>"su");INDEX($C$1:$1;MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("C"&row()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()));0;-5);$1:$1;0)-1;4);1;"")&row()));INDIRECT("C"&row()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()));0;-5);$1:$1;0)-1;4);1;"")&row());0));"w");"")`

I was wondering: is there an easier/simpler way to do this with google sheets formulas? Basically I want the range to be from `C1:<whatever letter is before the Total column>`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(B2<>"Sa",B2<>"Su"),INDEX($C$1:$1,MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,iferror(match("Total",$A$1:$1,0)-1,"No match"))),$1:$1,0)-1,4),1,"")&ROW())),INDIRECT("C"&ROW()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,iferror(match("Total",$A$1:$1,0)-1,"No match"))),$1:$1,0)-1,4),1,"")&ROW()),0)),"weekend"),"")
```

What we do is replace the


```
OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())),0,-5)
```

 part of the formula with


```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,iferror(match("Total",$A$1:$1,0)-1,"No match")))
```

`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,iferror(match("Total",$A$1:$1,0),"No match")))` will always return the column `Total` no matter where placed.
By adding `-1` it will return the column before `Total`, thus eliminating the need for the the `OFFSET` function.

Comment: Has the provided formula work for you? If not let us know why. If it did, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Your formula works, but it doesn't address the question, which is to provide a simpler/shorter solution than the one provided above (yours is longer).

Comment: _"Basically I want the range to be from C1:<whatever letter is before the Total column>"_ From what I understand and remember when looking at your sheet, you hadn't solved that issue. Anyway...